# Bioinformatics add-on

Tags: orange, bioinformatics

I would like to ask you why there are no Volcano-plot or MA-plot widgets in bioinformatics add-on already? As I can see it in the youtube video tutorial (two years ago, version 3.3). In the latest version, a functionality of making Volcano-plot disappeared. My question is why and or where?

[image]

Comment: There is a volcano plot widget available in Bioinformatics 3.2.7